# Tapping polyline does nothing - Google Maps IOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-polyline

Have read similar posts and tried their solutions but nothing's working for me. Have super simple Google Maps SDK 1.9.x example running on IOS Simulator through XCode 6.x, when I tap (OK, really clicking in the simulator, does that make a difference?) nothing gets logged as the code would lead me to believe it would, so it appears didTapOverlay never gets called.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:43.5157
                                                            longitude:-114.2933
                                                                 zoom:14];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;


    GMSMutablePath *path2 = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50618099,-114.34367)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50624301,-114.343572)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50635399,-114.343333)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50644602,-114.34312)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50655801,-114.342884)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50667996,-114.342642)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.506801,-114.342368)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50693896,-114.342054)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50707299,-114.341756)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50719796,-114.341476)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50731196,-114.341215)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.507419,-114.340978)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.50751396,-114.340759)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.507607,-114.340546)];
    [path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.507736,-114.340248)];

    GMSPolyline *rectangle2 = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path2];
    rectangle2.spans = @[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:[UIColor redColor]]];
    rectangle2.tappable = true;
    rectangle2.strokeWidth = 10.f;

    rectangle2.map = mapView_;

    NSLog(@"The code runs through here!");

    self.view = mapView_;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"in didTapOverlay");
}
@end
```

Any ideas appreciated.

-- Bass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it will be easier if you can your camera initiation to the following:

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:43.5157
                                                            longitude:-114.34367
                                                                 zoom:14];
```

So you can see your polyline easily near your within your camera.

Then in your `ViewController.h` header file, change your interface to the following:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

So your view controller will be a GMSMapViewDelegate.

Lastly, below your `self.view = mapView_;` add this following line:

```
mapView_.delegate = self;
```

This line will assign your view controller (which is a GMSMapViewDelegate) to your mapView_'s delgate, so that your mapView_'s delegate will be a GMSMapViewDelegate, and the didTapOverlay method will be called.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that did just what I needed. Still getting used to the delegates.